# different views on a single list ( Android )

Tags: android, list, layout

Is there a way to make a list with different views?
I mean that row in posiotion X will have layout "X.xml"
and row number Z will have layout "Y.xml"?

I've tried to manipulate ListRowAdapter() and getView() in a few ways but with no success...

Comment: @user379425 can you select CommonsWare's answer as correct (assuming it does what it says it does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in another way:
in the ListRowAdapter -> getView()
I've made an if() statement on the inflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.X, null);
if(somthing)
{
row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.Y, null);
//whatever
}
and in the end: return row;
```

works like a charm :)

Answer (score 6):

> Hi, Is there a way to make a list with
>   different views? I mean that row in
>   posiotion X will have layout "X.xml"
>   and row number Z will have layout
>   "Y.xml"?

Sure.

Step #1: Create an `Adapter` class, by extending `BaseAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter`, `CursorAdapter`, etc.

Step #2: Implement `getViewTypeCount()` to return how many different row types there are

Step #3: Implement `getItemViewType()` to return a number between `0` and the value returned by `getViewTypeCount()`, indicating which row type a given position will use

Step #4: Override `getView()` (or `newView()` and `bindView()` for `CursorAdapter`) and have it create the right row

Comment: thanks for the quick response!

That is really helpful.
Is there any example that you know of? 
I learn faster from examples... :)

Comment: Well, you can look at: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView/Sections/ or http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/ -- the second one is a bit old

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it out of the box.  Depending on how different your layouts are, you might be able to come up with a single layout, and then show or hide elements of it in getView depending on the row.  If you set an item to Layout.GONE, its as if it isn't there.

Comment: that is what I currently have but I need to change that - one layout is just one TextView and the other is 6..